# Informix Golang client package

Tags: go, odbc, informix, unixodbc

I am new to Informix and I want to establish a connection to Informix in golang. I have come across 2 approaches.

1. The ifxgo package: The github doc "https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxGo"  didnt include any examples on how to import or use it.
2. alexbrainman/odbc: When I tried with the alexbrainman/ODBC package,it gave an error

> SQLDriverConnect: {IM002} [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name
> not found and no default driver specified

What must be the method to connect to Informix in golang?

Comment: That ifxgo repo does have 'ifx_test.go' at https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxGo/blob/master/ifx_test.go  It opens a connection, builds a table, and does a select. Might help a little; before a good answer comes along.